# CCNet: "Failing Tasks : FilteredSourceControl: CheckForModifications" error

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, version-control, ccnet-config

I've installed CCNet and now I'm trying to set up a link to our repository. When I visit the CCNet dashboard website the project shows up ok, but when I click the Force button I receive this error in the messages column:

Failing Tasks : FilteredSourceControl: CheckForModifications

If I log into the server as the account which I've specified CCNet should use to connect to the repository, and do an Update on the project by hand (i.e. using SVN.exe or TortoiseSVN) the update works fine. My sourcecontrol section of the CCNet.config file is below.

```
<sourcecontrol type="filtered">
  <sourceControlProvider type="svn" autoGetSource="true">
    <executable>E:\SVNServer\bin\svn.exe</executable>
    <trunkUrl>
      https://bserver.int:4443/trunk
    </trunkUrl>
    <workingDirectory>E:\buildserver</workingDirectory>
    <username>USER</username>
    <password>PASSWORD</password>
  </sourceControlProvider>
  <inclusionFilters>
    <pathFilter>
        <pattern>**/*.*</pattern>
    </pathFilter>
  </inclusionFilters>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Both the cruisecontrol.net website and google seem utterly devoid of any information on this error, other than that it probably relates to the inclusionfilter section in the block above. Can anyone provide any ideas?

Comment: I have no answers for you regarding CCNet but it sounds like you have just started. Let me suggest you look into JetBrains TeamCity. They have a very liberal free license. I had a full CI stack up and running in less than an hour with build notification widgets and VS integration.. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the log file indicated a untrusted certificate. I logged into the machine as the user and permanently accepted the certificate, and then set the CCNet service to run under the same user account.